# Subset sum problem -> large array, known number of subset elements

Tags: combinatorics

I have a large array of data, usually about 500 positive integer values (from 1 to 1 000 000).

I need to find which elements give a sum of X. Order doesn't matter. Number of elements in subset which solves the problem is known and usually about 1/5 N. Can it help in any way to create an algorithm, which will find all possible solutions significantly faster? Would it even matter with so many elements in array?

Comment: You want a solution of all the numbers in your array sum to X or just one solution?

Comment: I would need all solutions. I've edited it in original post.

Comment: Do you have any constraints on X?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, X is a constant value, which also is a positive integer. Apart from known number of subset elements, there isn't anything what could simplify finding solutions.

Comment: I'm only asking because often additional constraints can vastly simplify the problem. The worst case scenario here seems pretty bad to me. Your claim of linear average run time makes me suspicious there are additional constraints you hadn't mentioned.  If you're really just after improvements in your algorithm, you should edit a description of the algorithm into your post. Unfortunately, the improvements may end up being case specific (for both the array and X)